# Search Values by keys in multidimensional array and save them in database

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have an array that is multidimensional or nested, I'm not sure about the correct word. The thing is that I'm trying to look for a specific key, return its value and store it in my database in one iteration. This is what I've been trying but is creating me a lot of rows in my database when I just need 1.

```
  $arr = $json['confirmed_by_province'];

    foreach ($arr as $province) {
        $confirmedByStates = new ConfirmedByProvinces();
        foreach ($province as $key => $value) {
            if($key == 'ON') {
                $confirmedByProvinces->ontario = $value;
            }
            if($key == 'QB') {
                $confirmedByProvinces->quebec = $value;
            }
            $confirmedByProvinces->save();
        }
    };
```

Here is the data on the $arr variable:

```
 array:31 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "ON" => "60"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "QB" => "46"
  ]
```

Comment: You just need to move the `$confirmedByProvinces->save();` outside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: You never have `$arr = [0 => ['ON' => '60', 'QB' => '46'], ['ON' => '52', 'QB' => '38']]` - both together under one element of outside array - in other words, there is always only one of that choice in element?

Comment: @DanielJonguitud If you answer this question, I could maybe provide you faster solution. Question is: can elements of array 31 have both keys?

Comment: @Tpojka It is actually an array with 31 keys that has another key inside of them. I actually solve my problem and I marked the solution. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Maybe you find something interesting in my answer, who knows. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$confirmedByProvinces->save();` method out side of `$province` array.

```
     foreach ($arr as $province) {
        $confirmedByStates = new ConfirmedByProvinces();
        foreach ($province as $key => $value) {
            if($key == 'ON') {
                $confirmedByProvinces->ontario = $value;
            }
            if($key == 'QB') {
                $confirmedByProvinces->quebec = $value;
            }

        }
        $confirmedByProvinces->save();
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer also @james explanation was really nice. I would like to add that even though I did what you suggested I also had to move my new model declaration outside of the for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

The issue stems from your loop, if we actually stop and look at what is happening, it will make a lot more sense:

```
foreach ($arr as $province) {
    $confirmedByStates = new ConfirmedByProvinces();
    foreach ($province as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 'ON') {
            $confirmedByProvinces->ontario = $value;
        }
        if($key == 'QB') {
            $confirmedByProvinces->quebec = $value;
        }
        $confirmedByProvinces->save();
    }
};
```

For each iteration you are newing up a new model called `ConfirmedByProvinces`:

```
foreach ($arr as $province) {
    $confirmedByStates = new ConfirmedByProvinces();
//...
```

At the end of each iteration, you are then calling `save()`:

```
foreach ($arr as $province) {
//...
    $confirmedByProvinces->save();
```

As you can now see, each iteration of the outer loop will new up an instance of your `ConfirmedByProvinces` model and then save it on the inner loop, resulting in multiple rows for as many entries there are in your array.

@DilipHirapara's answer will solve your issue, but I figured a more in depth explanation would make it clear why it was a problem to begin with.

Comment: You got my +1. perfect explanation :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this really helps me to understand better where was my mistake and also what I was exactly doing

Answer (score 0):

Avoid as much as in your power DB actions in foreach loop. In case here, you can set all from loop into array and save it into DB in one query instead:

```
$insert = [];
foreach ($arr as $k => $province) {
    foreach ($province as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'ON') {
            $insert[$k]['ontario'] = $value;
        }
        if ($key == 'QB') {
            $insert[$k]['quebec'] = $value;
        }
    }
    // add timestamps here if needed since insert() method doesn't make that automatically
    // $insert[$k]['created_at'] = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    // $insert[$k]['updated_at'] = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
}

if (!empty($insert)) {
    $confirmedByStates = new ConfirmedByProvinces();
    $confirmedByStates->insert($insert); // one I/O with DB
}
```